# UITableViewCell won't move beyond it's row when in drag and drop edit mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm following [this official documentation by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH11-SW1). I'm trying to implement the drag and drop functionality on my `UITableView`. The problem is, that the rows won't move pass their rows. As you can see, they always bounce back:

[image: Bouncing]

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    // This gets called, when I reach a UITableViewCell above or below
    // the one UITableViewCell I'm dragging around. This is the part
    // where it always snaps back I think.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath
{
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath
}
```

I'm using the [DZNEmptyDataSet](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet) library and am not quite sure, if this meddles with the original functionality of the `UITableView`.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** I have created a new `ViewController` with a `TableView` in my project and it behaves exactly the same. If I try to implement this functionality in a new Project however, it simply works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The 'problem' was another library [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController). When enabling editing on my `TableView` I have to disable the `MMDrawerController` gestures. Here the code the fixed my problem:

```
///
/// Enable edit mode
///
func editEntries()
{
    self.disableDrawerFunctionality()
    self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Fertig", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "finishedEditing:")
}

func finishedEditing(sender: AnyObject)
{
    self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.barButtonItemEdit
    self.enableDrawerFunctionality()
}

// MARK: - Toggle Drawer functionalities

///
/// While in TableView edit mode: Be sure to disable the MMDrawer gestures, since the gestures will colide
/// with gestures of the TableView
///
func enableDrawerFunctionality()
{
    mm_drawerController.openDrawerGestureModeMask = .PanningCenterView
    mm_drawerController.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = .PanningDrawerView | .PanningCenterView
}

///
/// When leaving TableView edit mode: Re-enable the MMDrawer gestures after finishing editting the TableView
///
func disableDrawerFunctionality()
{
    mm_drawerController.openDrawerGestureModeMask = .None
    mm_drawerController.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = .None
}
```

Here the part of their **readme** which caught my attention:

> You are free to set whatever combination you want for opening and closing. Note that these gestures may impact touches sent to the child view controllers, so be sure to use these appropriately for your application. For example, you wouldn't want MMOpenDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView set if a MKMapView is your center view controller, since it would intercept the pan meant for moving around the map.